# laravel command php artisan make:model run all commands in Commands folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

Why php artisan run all commands in the folder Commands when I create a model for example ?
Did I made something wrong ?

Comment: have you tried `php artisan make:model Models/Modelname`

Comment: Its just an example php artisan tinker run the commands too, why ?

Comment: Why do you believe it runs all commands? what are the symptons etc.

Comment: I see the $this->info('blablabla') displaying before tinker runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel will `initialize` all the commands (**User** defined and **Default** commands) whenever you run **any** command in laravel application.

Which means don't perform any operation in `__construct` method of the commands.

For Example:

If you are performing any Databse operation in `__construct`  method of custom command it will perform Databse operation no matter what command to ran.

So Move all the logics and operations to `handle` method of command.

I have faced the same issue back in the day You can see the github [issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/32905) to clarify.

Answer (score -4):

Artisan is the command line interface included with **Laravel**. Artisan exists at the `root` of your application as the artisan script and provides a number of helpful commands that can assist you while you build your application.

See more at : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan